# rtc_engine_event_handler.cc:56 onError err 110 msg nullptr

Tags: flutter, dart, agora

```
  Future<void> initialize() async {
    if (appId.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _infoStrings.add('App ID missing, please provide your APP ID ');
        _infoStrings.add('Agora Engine is not starting');
      });
      return;
    }

    _engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await _engine.setClientRole(widget.role!);
    _addAgoraEventHandler();
    VideoEncoderConfiguration configuration = VideoEncoderConfiguration();
    configuration.dimensions = const VideoDimensions(width: 1920, height: 1080);
    await _engine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(configuration);
    await _engine.joinChannel(token, 'cha', null, 0);
  }

  void _addAgoraEventHandler() {
    _engine.setEventHandler(RtcEngineEventHandler(
      error: (code) {
        setState(() {
          final info = 'Error $code';
          _infoStrings.add(info);
        });
      },
      joinChannelSuccess: (channel, uid, elapsed) {
        print("join channel");
        setState(() {
          final info = 'Join Channel: $channel, uid: $uid';
          _infoStrings.add(info);
        });
      },
      leaveChannel: (stats) {
        print("leave channel");

        setState(() {
          _infoStrings.add('Leave Channel');
          _users.clear();
        });
      },
      userJoined: (uid, elapsed) {
        setState(() {
          final info = 'User Joined: $uid';
          _infoStrings.add(info);
          _users.add(uid);
        });
      },
      userOffline: (uid, elapsed) {
        setState(() {
          final info = 'User Offline: $uid';
          _infoStrings.add(info);
          _users.remove(uid);
        });
      },
      firstRemoteVideoFrame: (uid, width, height, elapsed) {
        setState(() {
          final info = 'First Remote Video: $uid ${width}x$height';
          _infoStrings.add(info);
        });
      },
    ));
  }

  Widget _viewRows() {
    final List<StatefulWidget> list = [];
    if (widget.role == ClientRole.Broadcaster) {
      list.add(const rtcLocalView.SurfaceView());
    }
    for (var uid in _users) {
      list.add(rtcRemoteView.SurfaceView(
        uid: uid,
        channelId: widget.channelName!,
      ));
    }
    final views = list;
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
        views.length,
        (index) => Expanded(
          child: views[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my terminal

```
Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.044] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/android/iris_rtc_engine_impl_android.cc:243 CallApi Android RtcEngine handle -5476376604236842752
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.045] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:114 CallApi ret 0 result 
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.056] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:104 CallApi api_type 132 params {"code":1}
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.056] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:114 CallApi ret 0 result general failure
W/        ( 5556): general failure
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.057] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:104 CallApi api_type 132 params {"code":1}
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.057] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:114 CallApi ret 0 result general failure
W/        ( 5556): general failure
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.063] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:129 CallApi api_type 20 params {"canvas":{"uid":0,"channelId":null,"renderMode":1,"mirrorMode":0}}
D/spdlog  ( 5556): [2024-03-27 10:36:41.063] [0] [debug] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/iris_rtc_engine.cc:139 CallApi ret 0 result 
I/PlatformViewsController( 5556): Hosting view in view hierarchy for platform view: 9
D/BufferQueueConsumer( 5556): [](id:15b40000002a,api:0,p:-1,c:5556) connect: controlledByApp=true
D/Surface ( 5556): lockHardwareCanvas
W/libc    ( 5556): Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.display.iris_x7.support"
D/OpenGLRenderer( 5556): makeCurrent grContext:0xb400007e588dd500 reset mTextureAvailable
```